# Join a text in the same field csv powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
$ColumnsToRemove  | ForEach-Object{

    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1,$_).EntireColumn.Delete();
    $sheet.Cells.Item($_,1) = -join '0044';
}
```

I am trying to join the number '0044' in the first column of a csv after deleting a few columns.
Could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a CSV file try to use `Import-CSV` and `Export-Csv` CmdLets to handle your file, it will be easier than Excel.

If you give an example of your CSV file, I can help you.